# Is this sequence defined correctly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have some expression to develop, and this result reflects the brute force I used to prove that expression, however, I don't know whether that sequence is true or false.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \log (x^n) = \log\left(x^{x/(1-x)^2}\right) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

At $n=0$ the sum term is 0, and $\ln(a^b) = b\ln a$
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \ln(x^n)
 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n \ln x \\
 &= x \ln x \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} \\
 &= x \ln x \frac{d}{dx} \left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \right] \\
 &= x \ln x \frac{d}{dx} \left[(1-x)^{-1}\right] \\ 
 &= x (\ln x) (1-x)^{-2} \\
 &= \ln \left( x ^{x/(1-x)^2}\right) 
\end{split}
$$
but the geometric series expansion is only valid for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^n\log x^n=nx^n\log x$$

and also  $\;nx^n=x\left(x^n\right)'\;$ , so for $\;|x|<1\;$ , we get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}\implies \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}\implies$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\log x^n=\log x\left(x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(x^n\right)'\right)=\log x\cdot \frac x{(1-x)^2}=\log x^{x/(1-x)^2}$$

so yes: your expression is correct... *for* $\;|x|<1\;$ . BTW, I'd rather leave the expression as $\;\cfrac{x\log x}{(1-x)^2}\;$ ...I think it is neater, not to mention that if $\;-1<x<0\;$ all the above is true...but then you mess up with complex logarithms

Comment: I appreciate all your answers